# table multiple word search in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function that search a word in a table. e.g.

TABLE

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <th>Band Name</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>John</td>
       <td>Lennon</td>
       <td>Beatles</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Paul</td>
       <td>McCartney</td>
       <td>Beatles</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>George</td>
       <td>Harrison</td>
       <td>Beatles</td>
   </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>Ringo</td>
       <td>Starr</td>
       <td>Beatles</td>
   </tr>
```

now. i have an input text box that if you put any word in there based on the table e.g Paul
the result will be a table that has only paul mccartney . and all the other td elements will be hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            if (!RegExp.escape) {
                RegExp.escape = function (s) {
                    return s.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
                };
            }
            ///search this table
            jQuery(function ($) {
                ///search this table
                $(' #search ').click(function () {
                    var searchthis = new RegExp($(' #emp_search ').val().replace(/\s+/, '|'), 'i');
                    $("table").find("tr").slice(1).each(function (index) {
                        var text = $.trim($(this).text());
                        $(this).toggle(searchthis.test(text));
                    });
```

Now, what i want to happen is..
what if i input a text containg "Paul Harrison", the result should be paul mccartney and george harrison.. is that possible? like inputting a multiple words and displaying a possible result? Im just new in jquery. and the codes above is not mine.. thanks in advance. :)

here is the demo
http://jsfiddle.net/wind_chime18/D6nzC/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a regex based search will be the best fit for this

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function (s) {
        return s.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
    };
}

jQuery(function ($) {
    var $table = $("table");
    var bands = [];
    $table.find('td:nth-child(3)').each(function () {
        var text = $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase();
        if ($.inArray(text, bands) == -1) {
            bands.push(text);
        }
    }).get();

    ///search this table
    $(' #search ').click(function () {
        var parts = $(' #emp_search ').val().split(/\s+/);

        var bns = [],
            i = 0,
            idx;
        while (i < parts.length) {
            idx = $.inArray(parts[i].toLowerCase(), bands);
            if (idx >= 0) {
                bns.push(parts.splice(i, 1)[0]);
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }

        var nameexp = parts.length ? new RegExp(parts.join('|'), 'im') : false;
        var bnexp = bns.length ? new RegExp(bns.join('|'), 'im') : false;

        $("table").find("tr").slice(1).each(function (index) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var name = $.trim($this.children().not(':nth-child(3)').text());
            var band = $.trim($this.children(':nth-child(3)').text());
            $(this).toggle((!nameexp || nameexp.test(name)) && (!bnexp || bnexp.test(band)));
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D6nzC/)

Comment: we are having some problem. what if we have three columns. the third column is band name : beatles

Comment: and if i search like this. "beatles john"

Comment: @Vincent update the demo with the problem and the desired output

Comment: @Vincent what is the desired output

Comment: oh i'm sorry. try beatles john

Comment: or this "ringo beatles starr "

Comment: when you say `ringo beatles starr` which rows to be displayed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41841/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-vincent)

Comment: I want display the row of Ringo Starr

Comment: can i ask one last question. what if i want to find it in a specific column?

Comment: @Vincent which column and what value

Answer (score 0):

You could first `collapse` all the rows, then `split` the `searchthis` string on space and finally add `visible` to rows that match one of the rows... something like this for example.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ///search this table
    $('#search').click(function() {
        var searchthis = $('#emp_search').val();
        $("table").find("tr").each(function(index) {
            if (index === 0) return;
            $(this).css('visibility', 'collapse');
        });
        var searchArray = [searchthis];
        if (searchthis.indexOf(' ') > -1) {
            searchArray = searchthis.split(' ');
        }
        $("table").find("tr").each(function(index) {
            if (index === 0) return;
            var id = $(this).find("td").text().toLowerCase().trim();
            for (var i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
                var txt = searchArray[i].toLowerCase().trim();
                if (id.indexOf(txt) !== -1) {
                    $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: no. i mean.. the rows. and how it will show. instead of being collapsed.